# Android - My Global Variable values return null after switching Application

Tags: android, global-variables

I am Using GlobalVariable file to hold data during my entire application, but what happens is it returns null value if i switch to another application and returns back.

below is my code :

In Manifest :

```
 <application
    ..
    android:name=".MyApplication" >
```

For Class of global variables :

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
public int rowId = 0;
}
```

inside the activities

```
int mRowId = ((MyApplication) getApplicationContext()).rowId;
```

Comment: Make the rowId as static

Comment: try this `public final static int rowId = 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make it `static` and `final` but use it with getters and setters only.

Something like the following

```
 public class MyApplication extends Application {


 public final static int rowId = 0;
```

dont forget your initializing and setters and getters please :

```
 int rowId;

public int getRowId() {
    return rowId;
}

public void setRowId(int rowId) {
    this.rowId = rowId;
}
```

to set the values from outside the class, something like:

```
  MyApplication.rowId =  //whatever returns int
```

to get the values from outside/inside the class, something like:

```
  int TempInt = MyApplication.rowId; // TempInt will have the value of rowId
```

check What are setters and getters :
 https://dzone.com/articles/why-should-i-write-getters-and-setters

Comment: but you cannot set value to a final variable after initialising it.

Comment: if you want to change it after initializing it then just remove final and keep it public static. I thought your idea was just to hold the variable not to change it.

Comment: keep in mind though, this will then change. So dont forget to keep track of all your changes.